# A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 403 Forbidden

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Есть телеграм бот, написанный на telebot python.

С 01.03.2021 работал без проблем. Основная его задача - обработка и парсинг информации из документов, которые отправляют пользователи. также он обрабатывает несколько команд. Все иные типы данных он просто пересылает от пользователя к разработчику.

17.01.2022 внезапно в логах появилось 5 записей с ошибкой:

> A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 502 Description: Bad Gateway

Спустя примерно час каждый запрос от пользователей падал с ошибкой в логах:

> A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 403 Forbidden. Response body:
> [b'\r\n403 Forbidden\r\n\r\n
>
> ## 403 Forbidden
>
> \r\n
>
> ---
>
> nginx/1.18.0\r\n\r\n\r\n']

В процессе дебага удалось выяснить, что 403 ошибка падает при попытке скачать переданный документ в бота методом download_file() . Кусок кода, где все ломается:

```py
def handling_documents(message):
    def save_file():
        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(bot.get_file(message.document.file_id).file_path)
        filename = message.document.file_name
        logger.info(f"{message.chat.id} | {message.chat.username} | Sent document {filename} | {message.caption}")
```

Бот работает на CentOS (версию сейчас не назову). Проблема точно не в сервере, потому что на любом рабочем месте обработка документов не работает. Проблема именно в https://api.telegram.org/file/bot-token/file_path . Любые другие типы сообщений (фото, стикеры, текст и пр.) бот обрабатывает успешно, как надо.

Подходящего решения в гугле не нашел. Ботом ежедневно пользуются около 100 пользователей.
Просто ждать восстановления работоспособности,как написано в https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50772588/telegram-bot-file-download-suddenly-response-403 , увы, не могу.

Нашел также решение с отзывом API-токена https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/581
Но и после этого проблема с 403 ошибкой осталась. Что может быть не так?

Comment: какая версия библиотеки pyTelegramBotAPI? работает ли проблемная функция в IDE (прим. PyCharm) и/или вызовом из консоли (прим. python script.py) под Windows / Linux?

Comment: Обновил pyTelegramBotAPI до версии 4.3.1 и запустил на Linux Mint 20.2 в pyCharm скрипт.
Ошибка та же на строке
`
downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_path)
    print(f"{downloaded_file=}")`
`2022-01-18 23:51:20,579 (__init__.py:694 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 403 Forbidden. Response body:
[b'<html>\r\n<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n']"`

Comment: Дополню, что написал о проблеме в техподдержку телеграмм, но когда будет от них ответ - неизвестно. Единственное решение, которое не хотелось бы применять - удалить бота и снова создать его с тем же именем.

Comment: а с токеном другого бота такая же ошибка?

Comment: Если сделать нового бота, у него все обрабатывается хорошо. А у текущего даже смена токена не помогает

Comment: а на какой именно строке функции `save_file` проблема? и меня смущает что у вас функция в функции, хотя это и не нужно

Comment: Ошибка при выполнении `bot.download_file(...)`
Функция в функции только для сохранения файла на локальном сервере. Далее в функции `handling_documents` идет функция парсинга подписи к файлу, функция парсинга информации из файла (парсит сертификаты X509 формата *.cer), функция формирования ответного сообщения для пользователя.

Т.е. документ успешно передается на сервер телеграмма, но не скачивается из-за 403 ошибки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже все-таки это какой-то баг телеграм апи. Проблема решилась сама собой. Работоспособность восстановилась после простоя в 2 дня.